# What is the scheduler for Apache Mesos's Command Executor?

Tags: mesos

I'm studying Mesos code, become very confused about the internal working flow of executing a simple docker image, 
such as following:

```
mesos-execute  --master=XXX \
               --containerizer=docker \
               --name=test \
               --docker_image=XXX \
               --shell=false
```

I believe [`/src/cli/execute.cpp`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/src/cli/execute.cpp) is the implementation of this "mesos-execute", which is called "Command Executor" in the official document.

I see `execute.cpp` internally setups a [`CommandScheduler`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/src/cli/execute.cpp#L382), which has a [`void received(queue<Event> events)`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/src/cli/execute.cpp#L615) function that listens for events from the master. If it receives an [`Event::OFFERS`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/include/mesos/scheduler/scheduler.proto#L43), it will start the procedure of executing the tasks on the offered resources (agents).

However, I cannot find exactly where is the resource offered to the client executable. 
I see there is an [`void Master::offer(…)`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/src/master/master.cpp#L6840) function in [`/src/master/master.cpp`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/src/master/master.cpp). But it sends a [`ResourceOffersMessage`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/src/messages/messages.proto#L212), not an event, and no tranforming the event to a message. 
I find that only [`/src/sched/sched.cpp`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/src/sched/sched.cpp) can receive and process this type of message. But I don't see how is `sched.cpp` used in other code....

So, I cannot find the exact workflow of sending the offered resource (from master), to the Command Executor.  **What's the scheduler for this Command Executor?** 
Could someone help me to understand?

Thanks

Comment: [Answer on user@mesos.apache.org mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/87338ff42426702b19d441c5122dae50991f9940b41a0273d939a959@%3Cuser.mesos.apache.org%3E)

Comment: And duplicated question with different [answer on dev@mesos.apache.org mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/1fb2baa2f89c5cd9eb30da9c613cad89a37a1ab0012eec2e0a6a81e1@%3Cdev.mesos.apache.org%3E)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe [`/src/cli/execute.cpp`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/src/cli/execute.cpp) is the implementation of this "mesos-execute", which is called "Command Executor" in the official document.

**Command Executor** is a generic executor that according to documentation has [*"enough functionality for a wide variety of framework requirements"*](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/app-framework-development-guide/). Executor is responsible for launching a task described in [`TaskInfo`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/include/mesos/mesos.proto#L1543-L1550) message prepared by scheduler.

Indeed, Master sends a resource offer message but it [`evolve`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/src/internal/evolve.cpp#L345-L354)s to full event with proper type.

CLI uses [`scheduler::Mesos`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/include/mesos/v1/scheduler.hpp#L55-L65) which according to docs is *"concrete implementation that connects a scheduler to a Mesos master. Abstracts master detection (connection and disconnection)."* `received` is passed a a callback and called by this lib.

Comment: Thanks, the evolve() function is the key, it transform message to the correct event.   This is quite confusing, Mesos has two set of communication systems, via messages, or via events.    My understanding is that, message is some kind of legacy, they are switching to the events-based approach, right?

Comment: Yes, Mesos introduced event based HTTP API and old messages needs to be evolved. [_We need to evolve the internal old style message/unversioned event into a versioned event e.g., `v1::scheduler::Event` or `v1::master::Event`._](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/5dd1dd3b0d77ee6902af705a112f79b2b847644c/src/master/master.hpp#L281)